# What does "." (Dot) do in Visual Studio Code "runtimeArgs" property of launch.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

Today, I opened up my Visual Studio Code and saw that a new update has been released. Like any other normal (and ignorant) user, I just installed the update without any research about the changes. It's been months since I haven't had a problem with the updates so I assumed this one would be no different. But after the update, "launch" options would no longer work!

I have an Electron/Angularjs app. This launch config simply runs the app. Everything was working fine before the VS Code update but after the latest update (v 1.22.1), the app fails to launch from within VS Code.
I can, however, run my app through command line, so there are no changes/problems with Electron or others. The main Electron process would fail to find a module at $workspaceFolder (something about electron.asar resolvePaths?).

After a couple of hours of research, I found out that adding this simple property, grants my wish:

```
"runtimeArgs": [
    "."
]
```

Does anyone know what this little guy does in VS Code `launch.json`?

Here's the full `launch.json` in case you need it:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Electron",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
        "windows": {
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
        },
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Src/main.js",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "."
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dot "." would pass your current working directory(`cwd`) to `runtimeExecutable` 
,which in this case is `.bin/electron`.

So this executes

```
$ electron .
```

I'm guessing`"program": "${workspaceFolder}/Src/main.js"` is redundant and can be removed, because electron accepts a directory as path , given there's a package file in it.

Comment: So the second argument after `electron` is the directory path. Thank you for clarifying this. And you are also right about the "program" property, it is redundant as I have mentioned the "main.js" file in package.json, but I hadn't noticed the relation between the two. Thanks again.